# sys.stdout.write in python not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, sh

Consider the following code snippet

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sh
import sys

sys.stdout.write("hello")
sh.whoami(_out=sys.stdout.buffer)
```

I expect the above program to print

```
hello
username
```

but instead i get

```
username
hello
```

Can anyone please explain me why this is happening? I am using python 3.5.2 on linux mint 18.1

Answer (score 0):

That's output buffering for you. If you did:

```
sys.stdout.write("hello")
sys.stdout.flush()
sh.whoami(_out=sys.stdout.buffer)
```

the order would be as you expected.

Comment: In that case shouldn't sh.whoami() call should also be buffered after "hello"